# Nested List Loop

Tags: python, list, class, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to loop the nest list `['sally','joe']` in the example shown below.

```
data = ['joe','mike',['sally','joe'],'phil']
```

I attempted the following:

```
for i in data:
    for j in (i):
        if type(j) == '<class '+"'list'>":    
            print(j)
```

Comment: Please show your desired output. Is it `['sally','joe']` or is it `joe mike sally joe phil` (with newlines between)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `isinstance`:

```
for i in data:
    if isinstance(i,list):
        print(i)
```

Now the output is:

```
['sally', 'joe']
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use:

```
if type(j) == list:
    print(j)
```

It doesn't currently work because `type(j)` returns an object of class type, not a string. You might think it is a string because when printing it in a REPL interpreter, you might see the `repr(..)` version.

Comment: Downvoter: Care to comment? This answer was supposed to be "what went wrong?" and not "what's the right way".